# python: running a loop over indexes of a sub list

Tags: python, list

```
for items in things:
    while inputFloat != 0:
        thingsBack[][1]=inputFloat//things[]
        inputFloat=inputFloat-(things[]*thingsBack[][1])
```

things is a list of n elements, while thingsBack is a list with n sub-lists. I want both things and thingsBack to start at the 0th element and to loop through the recursion. The calculation inputFloat//things[] only changes the 1 index of the j-th sublist in thingsBack. i know [] is invalid syntax, but used for illustrative purposes.

it seems like there would be an obvious solution, but I am not seeing it.

Comment: Can you add sample inputs? and your expected output maybe? Your question a little unclear like this.

Comment: Also, if `inputFloat` is actually a float then it's highly unlikely it will ever be _exactly_ zero. [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: What do you mean by the j-th sublist?

Comment: And how about `things[]`?

Answer (score 2):

Taking a guess, I think you are looking for the index of the current item in your for loop?

```
for index, items in enumerate(things):
    # do stuff using index
```

Check this out:

[Accessing the index in Python 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops)

Answer (score 0):

You can use several different approaches

- A `range` based `for` loop

  ```
  for i in range(len(things)):
      thingsBack[i][1] = inputFloat // things[i]
      # etc.
  ```
- Loop over the elements of `things` using `enumerate`, to also get the index

  ```
  for i, thing in enumerate(things):
      thingsBack[i][1] = inputFloat // thing
      # etc.
  ```
- Loop over a zipped list of `things` and `thingsBack`

  ```
  for thing, thingBack in zip(things, thingsBack):
      thingBack[1] = inputFloat // thing
      # etc.
  ```